# Tap and Hold (Long Press)

Tags: windows-phone-7, long-press, tapandhold

Has anyone implemented Tap & Hold in a Windows Phone 7 App yet? I can see a couple of possible approaches KeyDown/KeyUp and a timer or ManipulationStarted/manipulationCompleted and a timer.
However it strikes me that this is a less than idea approach because different apps would have different timer settings leading to inconsistency.
Am I missing something? I was hoping for a TapAndHold event

Answer (score 6):

For all views Hold method is there.
It will handle long press function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the same situation, and I'm looking for "the recommended way". In the meantime, Mike Francis posted [a solution on his blog](http://blog.mjfnet.com/2010/07/16/windows-phone-7-detecting-tap-and-hold/), using [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touchpanel.aspx)'s gesture recognition within a Silverlight app. I didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was pretty much the solution I was contemplating. I wonder if this is something missing from the beta?

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone adds easy to use gestures support, including On Hold gestures

Answer (score 0):

Start the Timer on Hold Event of GestureLister

and stop it on GestureCompleted event this is really a trick see detail answer on following link

[How do I detect when toolkit:GestureListener Hold has stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747675/how-do-i-detect-when-toolkitgesturelistener-hold-has-stopped)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Hold += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(HoldEventHandler);
```

The above code should work for touch and hold event