# How do I detect when toolkit:GestureListener Hold has stopped?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, gesture

Is there a way I can detect this? I want to keep performing an action as long as the user is holding on an icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Amresh Kumar was correct in suggesting using the manipulation events. Also, I was given the same advice on the Windows Phone App Hubs forums so I've edited this post to reflect the code changes.**

Before, the UX was flaky because lifting my finger off the screen didn't always trigger a cancellation. Not surprisingly, the GestureCompleted code in the toolkit appears to be better geared towards touchscreens than are mouse button events.

XAML:

```
<iconControls:iconUpDownArrow>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="RangeUpTap" Hold="RangeUpHold" GestureCompleted="RangeUpCancel" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</iconControls:iconUpDownArrow>
```

code:

```
private void RangeUpTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    RangeIncrementUp(sender, e);
}

private readonly TimeSpan _rangeIncrementTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1500000);
private readonly DispatcherTimer _rangeIncrementTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

private void RangeUpHold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    _rangeIncrementTimer.Interval = _rangeIncrementTimeSpan;

    _rangeIncrementTimer.Tick += RangeIncrementUp;

    _rangeIncrementTimer.Start();
}

private void RangeUpCancel(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    _rangeIncrementTimer.Stop();

    _rangeIncrementTimer.Tick -= RangeIncrementUp;
}

private void RangeIncrementUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int range = Convert.ToInt32(tBoxRange.Text);

    if (range < 1000)
    {
        range += 10;
    }

    tBoxRange.Text = range.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the MouseUp/Down you can try Manipulation events.

Comment: Thanks Amresh. I was able to successfully change the code and reflected that in this sample.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `GestureListener` for this you could instead use the mouse manipulation events to detect how long to perform your action. For instance:

- Listen for `MouseLeftButtonDown` to know when the user has touched the icon
- Keep performing the action until either `MouseLeftButtonUp` or `MouseLeave` fire indicating that the user is no longer touching that icon
- You may also have to play with `MouseEnter` for initiating the action

Comment: I tried using some MouseLeftButton code I used successfully in an SL4 app, but it was flaky, sometimes not stopping when I'd lift my finger off the screen. Also, it conflicted with the Tap behavior because my mouse button code uses a DispatcherTimer. Anyway thanks for the reply. I'll keep tinkering with it.

Answer (score 1):

Today only i did the same thing in my project.I'll tell you the basic logic what i implemented(*assuming it has to be done on button*).
**Step 1:**

On the ***button*** _*ManipulationStarted*_ event start a timer with the **interval** after which you want to fire the repeat action.

**Step 2:**

On the ***button*** _*ManipulationCompleted*_ event stop the timer.

**Step 3:**

If the timer is *fired*,stop the timer and start another timer with **interval** = **the repeat interval for your action**.And inside the second timer *fire* handler perform your operation only if the **control** has *focus*. In this case, where the control is a **button**, you can check if the **button.IsPressed** is true then perform action.

The code will look something like:

```
Button forward=new Button();
DispatcherTimer forwardHoldTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
forward.ManipulationStarted += (a, b) => { forwardHoldTimer.Start(); };
forward.ManipulationCompleted += (c, d) => { forwardHoldTimer.Stop(); };
forwardHoldTimer.Tick+=(s1,e1)=>
{
        forwardHoldTimer.Stop();
        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100) };
        t.Tick += (x, y) =>
        {
             if (forward.IsPressed)
             {
                  //Your action logic will go here
             }
             else
                t.Stop();
         };
         t.Start();
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Amresh. I tried this out but couldn't make it work (out of my own lack of knowledge).

Comment: Hi, what is the control on which you want to implement the functionality??